# Listing Superseded Updates using powershell in WSUS 3

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate the process of managing WSUS reports. I managed to 
I) report the updates that I approve to WSUS console.
II) run a cleanup Process for the superseeding

So the script I use to list approved updated updates is:

```
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$updatescope.ApprovedStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ApprovedStates]::LatestRevisionApproved
$updatescope.FromArrivalDAte = [datetime]"10/08/2013"
$wsusgroup = $wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups() | Where {$_.Name -eq "PCM_WSUS_spec"}
$updatescope
$updatescope.gettype()
$updatescope.count
$updateScope.ApprovedComputerTargetGroups.add($wsusgroup)
$wsus.GetUpdates($updatescope) | Select KnowledgebaseArticles,Title
$Updates = $wsus.GetUpdates($updatescope) | Select KnowledgebaseArticles
```

What I really need is a function to list of the updates went superseded based on the aboce list; updates that got approved after the given date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To build a list of superseded updates will require you to know the current update. Superseded updates are maintained as a list of UpdateIDs associated with the current update. (The list of superseding updates is built by traversing that list backwards.)

In the actual package XML, it looks like this:

```
<sdp:SupersededPackages xmlns:sdp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wsus/2005/04/CorporatePublishing/SoftwareDistributionPackage.xsd">
  <sdp:PackageID>b87cc8c1-b03d-4548-aa53-f0138ec6e2a3</sdp:PackageID>
  <sdp:PackageID>7d8fcd7b-49d1-440d-8140-d6c33ce2cb80</sdp:PackageID>
  <sdp:PackageID>76f68136-436f-42a5-9029-560b23702416</sdp:PackageID>
  <sdp:PackageID>64b8c9d0-ecbc-4711-90de-b190d2ee7ee1</sdp:PackageID>
  <sdp:PackageID>6bd77c33-1b2d-450d-91c6-259e101e57bb</sdp:PackageID>
  <sdp:PackageID>94642c22-d70e-45b8-a70f-c09b86e2c4f5</sdp:PackageID>
</sdp:SupersededPackages>
```

But I do not know how it's actually accessed via the API (if even possible), or where in the database schema to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I achieved to get a list using the following  :

```
 '[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$WSUS = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::GetUpdateServer('wsupdates',$false,80) 
#creating the update scope. Different parameters can be used each time for different reports needed
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$updatescope.ApprovedStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ApprovedStates]::LatestRevisionApproved
$updatescope.FromArrivalDAte = [datetime]"10/08/2013"
$wsusgroup = $wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups() | Where {$_.Name -eq "PCM_WSUS_spec"}
$updateScope.ApprovedComputerTargetGroups.add($wsusgroup)
$updatescope
$updates = $wsus.GetUpdates($updatescope) | Select Title,UpdateClassificationTitle,SupersededUpdates | Sort Title |Export-csv 'C:\WSUS\test_approved.csv' -notype
$updates = $wsus.GetUpdates($updatescope) 
$updates 



$updates | ForEach-Object  {
$temp =$_
Write-Output ' temp is'
$temp
$temp | Select Title| Export-CSV 'C:\wsus\superseded.csv' -Append -Notype -Force
$SupersededOnes = $_.GetRelatedUpdates(([Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateRelationship]::UpdatesSupersededByThisUpdate)) |Select Title
Write-Output 'after finding out superseded'
$SupersededOnes
Start-Sleep 8
$SupersededOnes | Export-CSV 'C:\wsus\superseded.csv' -Append -Notype -Force
}'
```

My issue is it appends the superseded beneath the approved, I need them to the column besides the associating superseding update.